# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'exceptions' in python 3.6

Tags: python, windows, python-3.6

i installed `docx` package for python.

```
from docx import Document

document = Document('inp.docx')

for p in document.paragraphs:
    print(p.text)
```

when i run the code, it throws the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cont.py", line 1, in <module>
        from docx import Document
      File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\docx.py", line 30, in <module>
        from exceptions import PendingDeprecationWarning
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'exceptions'
```

please suggest the solution.

Comment: I got the same thing.